# What's the proper way to set CachingStrategy to RecycleElement in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I've been getting an error (but my code still runs with it so I've been ignoring it until now) saying that my `BindableListView is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter`.

I'm guessing this is the cause of another crash I'm getting: `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsTextView'`
because I've seen suggestions online saying that most of the time, this issue is related to the ListView, and that I should set the CachingStrategy to RecycleElement.

So I decided to finally take a look at the BindableListView and add in the `CachingStrategy = "RecycleElement"`

Now there was already some code implemented that seemed to try and add the CachingStrategy already:

BindableListView.cs:

```
namespace MyApp.Core.Controls
{
    [PropertyChanged.DoNotNotify]
    public class BindableListView : ListView
    {
        public static BindableProperty ItemClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemClicked), typeof(ICommand), typeof(BindableListView));
        public static BindableProperty ItemAppearsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemAppears), typeof(ICommand), typeof(BindableListView));
        public static BindableProperty AnimateScrollToSelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AnimateScrollToSelectedItem), typeof(bool), typeof(BindableListView), true);

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a <see cref="BindableListView"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cachingStrategy">Sets the caching strategy for the <see cref="ListView"/>.</param>
        /// <example><![CDATA[
        /// <controls:BindableListView>
        ///  <x:Arguments>
        ///    <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
        ///  </x:Arguments>
        /// </controls:BindableListView>
        /// ]]></example>
        public BindableListView(ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy)
            : base(cachingStrategy)
        {
            ItemTapped += OnItemTapped;
            ItemAppearing += OnItemAppearing;
            ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
    ...
```

Then in all the .xaml files that use this ListView:

```
<controls:BindableListView
      ...>
      <x:Arguments>
        <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
      </x:Arguments>
```

Would this be the correct way to set CachingStrategy to Recycle Element? If so then how would I go about fixing my error(s)?

Or should I remove the parameter from the constructor in BindableListView.cs to make it parameterless, and then just add the one line `CachingStrategy = "RecycleElement"` ? I tried this and the error went away at least.. (app won't run now though, "missing default ctor") but I don't know if it's the right thing to do. If this is what I'm supposed to do, will this fix my second error as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The part of the error message that applies to your situation is:

> ... does not define a public parameterless constructor ...

Change this:

```
public BindableListView(ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy)
            : base(cachingStrategy)
{
    ItemTapped += OnItemTapped;
    ItemAppearing += OnItemAppearing;
    ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
public BindableListView(ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy)
        : base(cachingStrategy)
{
    Init();
}

public BindableListView()
        : base()
{
    Init();
}

private void Init()
{
    ItemTapped += OnItemTapped;
    ItemAppearing += OnItemAppearing;
    ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
    ...
}
```

Note that you *do* want to keep your parameterized constructor (XAML needs that); so the solution is to add a *second* (parameterless) constructor.

Thus you will have both forms of constructor that are needed, and each of them will perform your initialization logic.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think it is the correct way to set CachingStrategy to Recycle Element.

According to this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

The solution to this issue is to specify a constructor on the subclassed ListView that accepts a ListViewCachingStrategy parameter and passes it into the base class:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{

   public CustomListView (ListViewCachingStrategy strategy) : base (strategy)
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

Then the ListViewCachingStrategy enumeration value can be specified from XAML by using the x:Arguments syntax

```
<local:CustomListView>
<x:Arguments>
    <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
</x:Arguments>
```